# Disable VSCode ESLint warnings, but keep formatting functionality

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I am using VSCode's ESLint extension to fix and format my TS code. I would like to remove all the warnings (such as red underlines) from ESLint, because I find them really annoying and distracting.

Using the config

```
"eslint.enable": true,
```

removes all warnings, but also disables the formatting.

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: No, I didn't find anything.

Comment: I think I found an answer, I'll draft one for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VS Code settings you can define an entry called `"eslint.rules.customizations"` and provide an array of rules with a severity setting set to "off".

```json
{
  "eslint.rules.customizations": [
    { "rule": "<rule-name>", "severity": "off" }
  ],
}
```

For example, if you are trying to remove the red (error) or yellow (warn) squigglies for the rules `"react/jsx-curly-brace-presence"` and `"prettier/prettier"` you can configure the following:

```json
{
  "eslint.rules.customizations": [
    { "rule": "prettier/prettier", "severity": "off" },
    { "rule": "react/jsx-curly-brace-presence", "severity": "off" }
  ]
}
```